# Investigate for convergence or divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\require{cancel}$
Investigate for convergence or divergence:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{3^n+4^n}{4^n+5^n}$$

I'm allowed to use basic tests for convergence or divergence:

- P-series test
- **Geometric series test**
- **n<sup>th</sup> Term test**
- Integral test
- **Comparison test**
- **Limit Comparison test**
- Ratio test
- Root test
- Alternating test

The bold items are the ones I think are more likely to be used in this problem as opposed to the others.

### Progress

So I made some progress but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I assume,
$$a_n=\frac{3^n+4^n}{4^n+5^n}$$
and,
$$b_n=\frac{\cancel{3^n}+4^n}{\cancel{4^n}+5^n}=\frac{4^n}{5^n}=\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$$
The reason I cancelled the $3^n$ and the $4^n$ is because they're insignificant when compared to $4^n$ and $5^n$, respectively.

At this point, I know that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_n$ converges, because it is a geometric series. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $3^n+4^n<2\cdot 4^n$; $4^n+5^n>5^n$

This implies
$$
\frac{1}{4^n+5^n}<\frac{1}{5^n}
$$
so
$$
\frac{3^n+4^n}{4^n+5^n}<2\frac{4^n}{5^n}
$$

Comment: That's interesting. Can you explain how you got to that conclusion please?

Comment: @null It's similar to your idea, but rigorous (which your idea isn't so much).

Comment: Wow, that makes sense, because if you multiply a convergent series by a constant, it still converges. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{3^n+4^n}{4^n+5^n} < \frac{\left( \frac {16} 5 \right)^n+4^n}{4^n+5^n} = \left( \frac 4 5 \right)^n
$$

So a basic comparison with a geometric series does it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that fast with equivalents:

$3^n+4^n\sim_\infty4^n$, $\;4^n+5^n\sim_\infty5^n$, hence
$$ \frac{3^n+4^n}{4^n+5^n}\sim_\infty\frac{4^n}{5^n}=\biggl(\frac45\biggr)^n, $$
which converges. Now two equivalent series with positive terms both converge of both diverge.